# Запретить вращение объекта по векторам в Unity

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема в Unity. Необходимо привязать некий объект к кости персонажа, которая анимирована. Как сделать так чтобы  привязка шла только по координатам без вращения(или запретить вращение по 2-м лишним векторам которые мне не нужны), но оставить его перемещение в пространстве вслед за костью. Спасибо за помощь!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Вот так я распологаю оружие до старта сцены и привязываю к кисти персонажа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так оружие вращается после проигрывания анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так нужно чтобы было после проигрывания анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Я на последних 2-ух картинках его выровнял вручную но нужно чтобы он и не вращался, а точнее вращался только по одному вектору вроде как только по Y вектору.

Всем огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: В RigidBody есть заморозка перемещения и вращения по любому из трех направлений

Comment: надеюсь он разобрался сам за 9 месяцев:)

Answer (score 1):

В компоненте `RigidBody` существует заморозка поворота (`Freeze Rotation`);